# Android Studio. Align multiple text boxes under multiple check boxes and equal spacing to fit screen

Tags: java, android, checkbox, textbox, alignment

[This is what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frxos.jpg)
 But 
[this is what i get when uploaded on phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRHzZ.jpg)

It seems ok in android studio fragment design preview but when uploaded on phone
checkboxes are not displayed :(.

Any better solutions?

Below is full xml code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:text="@string/getnotif"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/mcall"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:text="@string/msms"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="23:59"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Days"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:paddingLeft="-27dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:paddingLeft="-26dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:paddingLeft="-27dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:paddingLeft="-27dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:paddingLeft="-24dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:paddingLeft="-25dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:paddingLeft="-27dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/from"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Time"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't managed to align properly the text boxes under the check boxes. 
I have inserted the layout into a scroll view and i can properly see all of them know. 
It is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set all your checkboxes with layout_weight=1 inside a LinearLayout. Set the Linear Layout's orientation to vertical.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mon"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tue"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wed"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Thu"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"/>
```

Comment: Used layout weight 1 for check boxes and linear layout orientation vertical.
See my next answer for results :(

Answer (score 0):

```
I  have tested your design in an activity , it's displaying fine in full screen. 
[![like this][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B1hz.png

Make sure you have given Fragment width and height to match parent.
<Fragment
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: the same result i get also on android studio preview...but when uploaded the apk i still got the img that i have posted previously :( Maybe screen size of my phone is to small and the checkboxes doesn't fit aligned like that?    (5.3 inch and 480 x 854 pixels resolution)

Comment: can you share the main_layout design , where the fragment you are using.. And I tested the code as Activity in 4.30 inch display.

Answer (score 0):

[New androidtudio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM8hF.jpg)
And 
[the result on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65t0H.jpg)

Bellow is code modified as you suggested.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:text="@string/getnotif"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/mcall"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:text="@string/msms"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="23:59"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Days"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MON"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TUE"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WED"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="THU"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FRI"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAT"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SUN"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/from"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Time"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```